Handling axodraw in LaTeX: challenges with compatibility and workflow
I handle the formatting of scientific articles, and an author recently submitted a paper that included the use of the axodraw package. This presented several challenges as it required me to compile the .tex file using latex instead of pdflatex, and then convert it to a PDF using dvipdf. Unfortunately, the majority of the tools I rely on for automating formatting tasks and conducting necessary checks are designed to work with pdflatex.
To address this issue, I resorted to extracting "manually" the figures from the PDF generated by dvipdf and incorporating them into the document using \includegraphics.
\begin{figure}
\centering
%% \begin{equation*}
%% \hspace*{-15mm}
%%  \vertNLOa \hspace*{1mm} = \hspace*{2mm}
%%  \vertNLOb \hspace*{5mm} +
%%  \vertNLOc \hspace*{5mm} +
%%  \vertNLOd \hspace*{10mm} +
%%  \vertNLOe \hspace*{10mm} - \hspace*{4mm}
%%  \vertNLOf
%% \end{equation*}

\includegraphics{figure1-cropped.pdf}

\caption{....}
\end{figure}

This involved commenting out the original code used to generate the images. While I recognize that this approach may not be ideal, I exhausted all other options before implementing it.
Moving forward, I'm considering whether there might have been a better way to handle this situation. Additionally, I'm contemplating whether it would be appropriate to suggest to the author the possibility of switching to axodraw2 (that allows pdflatex) for future projects (keep in mind that I'm just a copy editor, and my knowledge of axodraw* is limited to what's necessary to avoid compilation errors). While it's not common practice for us to provide this type of feedback to authors, it could potentially alleviate similar challenges in the future.
Note added. I thought I had explained it, but I would like to clarify further that I am not the author of the document. I received it from the author, the scientist who wants to publish their study, and my role is solely to modify it to conform to the style of the journal in which it will be published (we publish online in PDF format). Therefore, I am not the one who can choose whether and how to use packages that generate this type of figure.
What I failed to specify, as David Carlisle pointed out, is that the author provided, along with the document, an axodraw.sty file.
It is not fair to blame me for the use of this package. My responsibility is simply to deal with it.
My question is: what do you think is the most appropriate way to handle these cases, both from a technical perspective and from the standpoint of our relationship with the authors?

you have provided no example of the input or of the problem you are having. texlive has no package called axodraw only a package axodraw2 which you say you are not using. Please fix the question to have more information.

This package is still using LaTeX 2.09. There are better ways to draw Feynman diagrams now. You just wasting time. Best would have been to use one of the newer packages and better supported ones.

@DavidCarlisle I've added a note to explain the issue more clearly. My problem is that using this package forces me to use the latex command instead of pdflatex. Since almost 99.9% of the papers we receive don't have issues with pdflatex, the tools we use for formatting automation aren't designed to transition from latex to dvipdf. I was wondering if it might be appropriate to encourage the author to switch to axodraw2 for their future work.

How to communicate with your customers does not sound like a latex problem. Maybe better suited for https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ ?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I wasn't aware of this forum. Thank you.

you don't even need to change the document since it's a custom style (about which you have given no information other than its name, presumably the one in the ctan legacy area, but not in distributions)  simply save the standard axodraw2.sty as axodraw.sty. If that generates an error, make an example and ask about that. There is nothing in this question that can really be answered on this site.

@DavidCarlisle Actually, the response you just provided is quite helpful for me. I hadn't thought of that. If you think it's appropriate, please post this comment as an answer, and I'll be happy to accept it.

axodraw is not distributed in tex distributions, although a copy can be found in the legacy 2.09 area on ctan. It hasn't been updated to latex2e so has been obsolete for 30 years. If you do not want to change the document, just save a copy of axodraw2.sty locally as axodraw.sty. According to its documentation it should be mostly compatible, and any minor incompatibilities can be addressed as needed in the document.
